# how to add badge to ion-fab in ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I want to add a notification badge to my ion-fab, I want the badge to be at the top-right corner of the badge.
here is my code

```
<ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" translucent="true">
    <ion-fab-button id="cart-btn" color="danger">
         <ion-icon name="notifications-outline" class="icon-button inner-center-btn"></ion-icon>
         <ion-badge id="cart-badge" color="danger">6</ion-badge>
    </ion-fab-button>
</ion-fab>

#cart-btn {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    overflow: visible!important;
}


#cart-badge {
    position: absolute;
    top: 12%;
    right: 12%;
}
```

the notification badge does display inside the ion-fab but when I change the scss code to

```
#cart-btn {
    position: relative;
    top: -3px;
    right: -3px;
    overflow: visible!important;
}
```

the badge just disappears, please how can I add the badge so that it will be at the top-right corner of the ion-fab

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    <ion-fab vertical="bottom" horizontal="center" translucent="true">

        <ion-badge color="primary" style="left: -5px; z-index: 3; position: absolute;">11</ion-badge>

        <ion-fab-button id="cart-btn" color="danger">
             <ion-icon name="notifications-outline" class="icon-button inner-center-btn"></ion-icon>
             <ion-badge id="cart-badge" color="danger">6</ion-badge>
        </ion-fab-button>
    </ion-fab>
```

Comment: This worked, but without the `<ion-badge id="cart-badge" color="danger">6</ion-badge>` inside of the ion-fab-button for me. I also switched the color to danger of the ion badge